# Open Excel and load a .vsto add-in using Python

Tags: python, excel, vsto

I want to open the Excel application using Python. I have tried using the method below however it doesn't load add-ins by default. I have seen solutions for .xla based add-ins. Unfortunately the add-in I want to use is .vsto. Is this possible?

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 0):

> it doesn't load add-ins by default

COM add-ins should be loaded when you automate Office applications. It seems the problem is related to the add-in(s).

Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO Add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your VSTO Add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your VSTO Add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the `Startup` event handler in your VSTO Add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable a VSTO Add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled VSTO Add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the VSTO Add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the VSTO Add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the VSTO Add-in again. Read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in that has been disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-re-enable-a-vsto-add-in-that-has-been-disabled?view=vs-2019) article.

---

You can use the [Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.comaddin.connect) property of the `COMAddIn` class for checking out whether an add-in is enabled or not, and to force it load:

```
If Application.COMAddIns(1).Connect Then 
 MsgBox "The add-in is connected." 
Else 
 MsgBox "The add-in is not connected." 
End If
```